# Donet core Conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, warnings, csproj

I am currently working on major refactoring of project and in the process trying to remove all Warnings our code base had. Finally down to 11 Warnings, but can't really see what is going on with 9 of them, which all seem to be related. Something like:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of
>   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions" that could not be
>   resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when
>   log verbosity is set to
>   detailed. #######.Test.Integration    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2106

[image]

- I have Consolidated the nuget package versions.
- Checked the Csproj file and it seemed fine. (See below.)

All warnings are in Microsoft.AspNetCore.*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FakeItEasy" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\###\###API.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\###\###.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\###\###.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Looks like some has asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139375/warningnetsdk1071a-packagereference-to-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-specified-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the web SDK (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` instead of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`) and add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` without specifying a version

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />  
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Refer to [Integration and unit tests no longer work on ASP.NET Core 2.1 failing to find assemblies at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401152/integration-and-unit-tests-no-longer-work-on-asp-net-core-2-1-failing-to-find-as)

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2253